# Does X.org and VNC serers requide a video card?

Tags: virtualbox, vnc, x11, xorg

Can I use VBoxHeadless virtual machine as a X-server for remote users?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. Have `Xvnc` take the place of `Xorg` as the X server.

Comment: Excuse me, it's my fault, I've set the question ambiguous. Absolutely requires a video card, or absolutely able to work on a headless server?

Comment: Xvnc does not need a video card for normal operation. In fact, it will ignore it even if one is present, and it can operate in parallel with a normal X server.